# How use optional Equatable realization in generics?

Tags: swift

The simple use of Equatable protocol on optional types does not lead to any errors and works correctly.

```
var pA: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?
var pB: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?
print(pA == pB);
```

But what if I want to specify type in the `associatedtype`?

Sample code:

```
protocol WrapperProtocol {
    associatedtype IntegralType: Equatable

    init(_ value: IntegralType)
}

// all ok
struct Wrapper: WrapperProtocol {
    var val: UnsafeMutableRawPointer

    public init(_ value: UnsafeMutableRawPointer) {
        val = value
    }
}

// does not conform to 'Equatable'
struct WrapperOptional: WrapperProtocol {
    var val: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?

    public init(_ value: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        val = value
    }
}
```

Comment: And what will it give me? If error because `UnsafeMutableRawPointer?` not implement `Equatable` protocol.

Comment: My first comment was misleading, I have delete it. But `UnsafeMutableRawPointer?` does *not* conform to `Equatable`. `print(pA == pB)`  compiles because there is a `==` operator taking *optional* equatable operands.

Comment: If you change your protocol `init` function declaration to accept optional IntegralType, the first struct will fail, the second one will be ok.

Comment: Yes, but I need support for both options. I see 2 solutions: Write extension for UnsafeMutableRawPointer(but I think is not possible), or use alternative type like uintptr instead UnsafeMutableRawPointer for working with pointers without an optional.